# How to calculate the bimester of the year?

Tags: date, calculated-columns

a question how can I create a column based on a date that tells me to which bimester of the year it belongs?

For example, with this function I calculate the quarter, but I have not been able to calculate the bimester, does the .dt function have one already created?

data_2020['TRIMESTRE'] = data_2020['FECHA_COMPRA'].dt.quarter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Current **Bimester** number with **PHP**:

```
$BimNum = (int)ceil((int)date('m')/2);
```